# Tcl/Tk : Is there a way to get the list of options and commands of a Tcl/Tk widget using instrospection or reflection?

Tags: reflection, tcl, tk-toolkit, introspection

Tcl/Tk : Is there a way to get the list of options and commands of a Tcl/Tk widget using introspection or refection from Tcl ?

I was thinking at something like the Python : `X.__dict__` which returns a dictionary of properties of an arbitrary object x.

I tried `info` and `winfo` but it does not seem to do the trick

If is is possible to access these properties by code, it would save me the effort to code them by hand, widget by widget (I am trying to create "yet another Tcl/Tk" binding ...)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If `.x` is the path to a widget, `.x configure` gives you a list of lists where the first item in each list is an option for the widget. `.x notawidgetcommand` gives you an error message which enumerates the commands, maybe you can do something with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of options for a widget, use the `configure` command without extra options.

```
% button .b
.b
% puts [join [lmap c [.b configure ] {if {[llength $c] == 2} continue; lindex $c 0}] \n]
-activebackground
-activeforeground
-anchor
-background
-bitmap
-borderwidth
-command
-compound
-cursor
-default
-disabledforeground
-font
-foreground
-height
-highlightbackground
-highlightcolor
-highlightthickness
-image
-justify
-overrelief
-padx
-pady
-relief
-repeatdelay
-repeatinterval
-state
-takefocus
-text
-textvariable
-underline
-width
-wraplength
```

If you've not got 8.6, you'd instead have to do:

```
foreach config [.b configure] {
    if {[llength $config] == 2} continue
    puts [lindex $config 0]
}
# Same output
```

The easiest way of getting the list of subcommands (but you can call them methods if you want) is by looking at the error message.

```
% .b ?
bad option "?": must be cget, configure, flash, or invoke
```

Buttons don't have that many subcommands.

You *could* script that with `catch` and some regexps, and the format of the message is very stylised, but there's not all that much point except interactively; code won't know *when* to use a method (and won't have a much better idea about *how* to use it). Once you've taught it that, you don't need the generic introspector so much…

---

All widgets will have `configure` and `cget`. If it doesn't, it's not a widget. Everything else depends on the class. You can get that with `winfo class`, but some widgets can be mutated at creation. There's no substitute for reading the documentation… except asking *specific* questions here, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc saveOptions {} {
    set f [open saved_defaults w+]
    foreach w {button checkbutton \
         radiobutton menubutton \
         entry menu label spinbox \
         listbox canvas scrollbar scale frame} {
        set x [$w .xx]        
        foreach b [$x configure] {
            if {[llength $b] == 2} continue;
            puts $f "*[string totitle $w].[lindex $b 1]:[lindex $b end]"
        }
        destroy $x
      }
      close $f
  }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem?